# How much will this person be worth in $n$ months?

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance

Problem:

A person has a net worth of $0$. In their first month they increase their net worth be $100$. In the second month they increase their net worth by $200$. In the third month they increase their net worth by $300$. Hence after three months their net worth will be $600$.

What will their net worth be after $n$ months?

Answer:

Let $N$ be their net worth after $n$ months.
\begin{align*}
A &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} 100 \\
A &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 50(i)(i+1) \\
A &= 50 \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 + i \\
A &= 50 \left( \dfrac{ n(n+1)(2n+1) }{6} + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \right) \\
A &= 50 \left( \dfrac{ n(n+1)(2n+1) }{6} + \dfrac{3n^2+3n)}{6} \right) \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{25}{3}\right) ( (n^2+n)(2n+1) + 3n^2 + 3n ) \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{25}{3}\right) ( 2n^3 + 2n^2 + n^2 + n + 3n^2 + 3n ) \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{25}{3}\right) ( 2n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n ) \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ A = \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n ) $$

As a partial check, I will evaluate $A$ when $n = 2$.
\begin{align*}
A &= \ \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( 2^3 + 3(2^2) + 2(2) ) \\
A &= \ \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( 8 + 12 + 4 ) \\
A &= 400
\end{align*}
However, I should have gotten $300$.

As a partial check, I will evaluate $A$ when $n = 4$.
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( (4)^3 + 3(4)^2 + 2(4) ) \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( 64 + 3(16)+ 8 ) \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{50}{3}\right) ( 120 ) = 50(40) = 2000
\end{align*}
However, I should have gotten $1000$. Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer, which I now believe is right.

Let $N$ be his net worth after $n$ months.
\begin{align*}
A &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 100i \\
A &= \dfrac{ 100(n)(n+1)}{2} \\
A &= 50n^2 + 50n
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ A = 50n^2 + 50n $$

As a partial check, I will evaluate $A$ when $n = 2$.
\begin{align*}
A &= 50(2)^2 + 50(2) = 50(4)  + 100 \\
A &= 300
\end{align*}
It checks.

As a partial check, I will evaluate $A$ when $n = 4$.
\begin{align*}
A &= 50(4)^2 + 50(4) \\
A &= 50(16) + 200 = 1000
\end{align*}
It checks.

Comment: Just dividing by $100$, his net worth after $n$ months is $1+2+\cdots +n$, right?  So that's just $\frac {n(n+1)}2$.  Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @lulu - you have not misunderstood.  Multiplying back by $100$ gives $50n(n+1)$ which is not quite the expression in the second line, but for some reason this is then summed again.

Comment: @Henry  Yeah, that second sum threw me.  Probably just an error.

Comment: After two months you should have $100+200=300$ but you have calculated $(100)+(100+200) = 400$.  After four months  you should have $100+200+300+400=1000$ but you have calculated $(100)+(100+200)+(100+200+300)+(100+200+300+400) = 2000$.  You are over-summing and have the wrong sequence from Pascal's triangle or binomial coefficients: you want $100{n+2 \choose 2}$ but have $100 {n+3 \choose 3}$

Comment: @lulu You did not misunderstood the question. My original answer is wrong. I have posted a second answer.

Comment: Could somebody confirm that my answer is now right?

Comment: Consider it confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $A$ increases as $n$ increase. It does not increase exponential but it does increase faster than linearly. That is what I would expect in the  answer.

Now let's look at some special cases. The first is when $n  = 0$. In this case, we have:
$$ A = 50(0^2) + 50(0)  = 0 $$
Hence in this case, the formula checks. Now let's consider the case where $n = 6$. The right answer is:
$$100+200+300+400+500+600 = 2100$$
We have:
\begin{align*}
A &= 50n^2 + 50n \\
A &= 50(6^2) + 50(6) = 50(36) + 300 \\
A &= 2100 \\
\end{align*}
Hence it checks. Therefore, I  believe the second solution
posted is correct.